# Calling log4net from a singleton that is in a separate project stops all logging

Tags: c#, singleton, log4net

The application is a WinForms .net 3.5 app with multiple projects, one main project and multiple library projects. If I call log4net from a singleton that exists in one of the sub-projects it causes all logging to stop.

**Update**

Based on some of the comments I changed the TestSingletonLog4net class in the following ways. The problem still exists with these changes.

- Made the test class thread safe as Jon Skeet pointed this out.
- Changed the member declaration and added the  log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(); config call as per Norla's example with the same results, still whenever it is called all logging stops.

Here is the updated class to reproduce the problem.

```
    public class TestSingletonLog4Net
{
    private static volatile TestSingletonLog4Net instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    public static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(TestSingletonLog4Net));

    private  TestSingletonLog4Net()
    {
        log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();

        log.Info("Test write from singleton");
    }
    public static TestSingletonLog4Net Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
            {
                lock (syncRoot)
                {
                    if (instance == null)
                        instance = new TestSingletonLog4Net();
                }
            }

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

I setup a small project to duplicate the problem, and here is what is happening.

- if I use log4net from the main UI project with either singleton or normal class logging works.
- If I use log4net from sub-project libraries that are not a singleton logging works.
- If I attempt to use log4net from a singleton that is in one of the sub-project libraries all logging stops, not only does it not log but also logging done from main project no longer work either.

I originally had the log4net configuration as part of the app.config but I suspected it may be a problem so I moved log4net configuration into it's own config file.

Using log4net version 1.2.11

I have also tried calling log from outside the constructor with the same results.

The reset of my setup is below.

The following line is just below the using statements in my Program.cs

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

In each class I am calling log4net with:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Any advice for a resolution is greatly appreciated.

Comment: For one thing, your singleton implementation isn't thread-safe...

Comment: I originally found this problem while working with a different class that was implemented as a singleton trough an IOC container. I just made this test class to duplicate the problem without the IOC in the way.

Answer (score 1):

You should only be calling `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` **one** time in your application.  This should be called in the main application not in the class that contains the singleton.

Furthermore if you are going to call `log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();` the following line should be removed:

```
[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config", Watch = true)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got a singleton object that uses log4net.  Here's what I'm doing.

In the member declaration:

```
public static readonly log4net.ILog Logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof (TestSingletonLog4Net));
```

In the constructor:

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
```

That's it.  Haven't had any issues to date.  Please let me know if this does/does not work.

Comment: Thanks, tried your sample, updated code is in post above still did not work. Are your singletons in a separate project?

Comment: Just found this gem in a solution that references a logger in another project.  Good luck.  log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["LogName"] = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName;